# Storing information in text file as variables in C++

Tags: c++, input, format

I need help with C++ getting information from an *input* file and storing it as *different variables*. It is in the following format.

> us,northfields,Northfields,VA,9342,38.8042,-77.205

How would I go about doing this?

edit: Sorry, this is my first time using the forums. This is what I have so far.

```
#include "city.h"

void readLineOfData( istream& in, string &country,  string &city, string &city2, 
    string &state, int &pop, string &lat, string &longi);

void output( ostream& out, string country, string city, string city2,
    string state, int pop, string lat, string longi );

void cities( istream& in, ostream& out )
{
    ifstream ("cities.txt");
    string country, city, city2, state, lat, longi;
    int pop;
    readLineOfData(in, country, city, city2, state, pop, lat, longi);
    while(!in.fail())
    {

        output( cout, country, city, city2, state, pop, lat, longi );


        readLineOfData(in, country, city, city2, state, pop, lat, longi);
    }
    return;
}

void readLineOfData( istream& in, string &country,  string &city, string &city2, 
    string &state, int &pop, string &lat, string &longi)
{
    getline( in, country, ',');
    getline( in, city, ',');
    getline( in, city2, ',');
    getline( in, state, ',');
    in >> pop;
    in.ignore( 200, ',' );
    getline( in, lat, ',');
    getline( in, longi, '\n' );

}

void output( ostream& out, string country, string city, string city2,
    string state, int pop, string lat, string longi )
{
    out << country << endl;
    out << city << endl;
    out << city2 << endl;
    out << state << endl;
    out << pop << endl;
    out << lat << endl;
    out << longi << endl;
}
```

Currently I have it set up to set the variables. I have a header file that helps shorten the code. I now need to be able to identify the highest population, how would I go about doing this without using arrays?

Comment: This is not actually a good question for Stack Overflow. You are expected to come here basically conversant with programming. No need to be an expert, but you are expected to have read some documentation. To convince us that you are that far along you be able to tells us what you have tried and how it has let you down. You should be able to specify the question more precisely: is there always only one line of input or may there be many? Do you know exactly how many? Could any of the fields have commas in them or is `,` *always* a delimiter? Give us something to work with here!

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn them into real variables except by writing them into the source code.

The closest you can get is normally to store them in a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` with the intended "variable name" as the key.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> data;
std::ifstream in("file.txt");
std::string temp = "";
for(std::istream_iterator<char> iter(in); in; ++iter) {
  if(*iter == ',') {
    data.push_back(temp);
    temp = "";
  }
  else {
    temp += *iter;
  }
}
```

You can then access the different values as indices in the `data` buffer.